# React WalletSignatureError

Tags: reactjs, solana

I'm trying to use solana wallet adapter in my react app following the setup in https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter but says:

Attempted import error: 'WalletSignatureError' is not exported from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base'

[image]

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Working now, seems like a versions issue.

The versions I used are:

```
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.7.0",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.13.1",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.6.1",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.11.3",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think after `@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.7.0"` it no longer exists. Instead

```
 import {  TransactionSignature} from '@solana/web3.js'

  const confirmation = await awaitTransactionSignatureConfirmation(
      txid,
      DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
      connection,
      commitment,
    );

    if (!confirmation)
      throw new Error('Timed out awaiting confirmation on transaction');
```